# Need Info on linux command ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

Tags: linux, git, ssh-keygen

I have to access personal git repository at the university . I have been asked to Generate SSH key.

I am using this command to generate an SSH key:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Can I use my username instead of my email for this command? Like:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myusername"
```

Comment: Did you try? What happened?

Comment: ssh key generated but end part is like this..                                                                               emdPPTwPy1i4xtWzCszMzUkuYymDoWOPluY92SuXthjraQw== fadfdab@hotmail.no but i have me tood that SSH key should b like this   QWLmIXQvvf3ZpyPr0hfpgyXeCJDS8Plb83lCANwmiiIpT6MOjWvUQY2iRuplMU
4n1U1N0= mobilars      in the last there is username not email like my ssh key

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The part after the `-C` is just a comment to help you remember what this key is for. The username will be fine. You can also leave off the `-C your_email@example.com` part entirely.